# PHP barcode does not display using external class on PHP7

Tags: php, barcode, php-7

Sir, I have used the PHP **Barcode Generator Class** to generate Code 39 barcode;
I have used from http://www.shayanderson.com/php/php-barcode-generator-class-code-39.htm

Here is the code;

```
    //include Barcode39 class
include "Barcode39.php";

//set Barcode30 object
$bc = new Barcode39("Nimal Perera");

//display new barcode
$bc->draw();
```

When I run this, why would I get this error?

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\Barcode39.php on line 269
```

It mentions that requirements: Requirements: PHP Web server and GD Library (Graphics Library).

I do not what GD Library means? I have XAMPP server in localhost. Please help me.

UPDATE!!!

I am beginner to barcode programming. This is my first example. Please tell if this is the good library for me to start? or are there any libraries that is suitable for a beginner with examples and documentations? What libraries are popular?

UPDATE!!

I checked if I have installed GD. Here is screenshot

[image: GD]

Comment: Your exact code works for me and [runs without errors](https://3v4l.org/MPGTS) in all PHP versions > 5.0.2. You will need to install GD but this is not the appropriate forum for questions on installing libraries on your system. Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are also off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @MattRaines Sorry, I have GD support. But why do I get this error is strange

Comment: @MattRaines I get this couple of errors for lengthy of screen scrolls: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\Barcode39.php on line 269

Notice: Undefined variable: Array in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\Barcode39.php on line 269

Comment: Are you using PHP 7?

Comment: @MattRaines.PHP Version 7.0.2

Comment: It looks like I misinterpreted the 3v4l.org output then. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 5):

Line 269 of Barcode39.php is:

```
imagefilledrectangle($img, $bars[$i][0], $bars[$i][1], $bars[$i][2], $bars[$i][3], $$bars[$i][4]);
```

PHP 7.0 introduced a [backwards-incompatible change](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php) relating to the interpretation of `$$`. `$$foo['bar']['baz']` used to mean `${$foo['bar']['baz']}` and now means `($$foo)['bar']['baz']`.

You should be able to fix the problem by replacing line 269 in the library with:

```
imagefilledrectangle($img, $bars[$i][0], $bars[$i][1], $bars[$i][2], $bars[$i][3], ${$bars[$i][4]});
```

Then file a bug report with the author.

Comment: Ok Sir, thank you very much for your reply. Just read now. I will test and tell you. Meanwhile, I have been learning about barcode for whole days. Now I can understand some concepts. But still I could not see a good library with some basic examples. I also tried tcpdf.org. Barcode format can be anything for me to first I become familiar with barcode generating. Is there good popular library reliable unlike this one I mentioned in my post. Thanks

Comment: I don't have any experience with barcode libraries, sorry. Stack Overflow isn't an appropriate forum for requesting library suggestions either. They tend to attract subjective answers and spam.